# Flutter auth ui facebook sdk issue

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication, flutter-dependencies

An issue with Facebook SDK 
When I am trying to using [flutter firebase auth UI](https://github.com/fidelisa/flutter_plugins/tree/master/packages/flutter_firebase_ui) 
The app is crashing and I identify that it is because of facebook SDK setup and I am not interested in using Facebook login 
Is there any other soluction available for getting flutter firebase ui with google login, email login,phone login only

Comment: You can use packages individually (google_sign_in, local_auth and for email and password, you can call api directly).